# How can I reset the GNOME Shell theme for the main account from the guest account?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, themes

I tried out a GNOME Shell theme from gnome-look.org on my main account/login user. The theme must be broken because it won't load, and crashes that login. I am currently on the guest account. Is there any way to edit that account's theme to default from this account?

Answer (score 4):

Log in as your normal user. Just chose a different session at the login screen. After that you should be able to make the changes you need using `gnome-tweak-tool` or by some other means.

Comment: ah! thats brilliant!!! XD I never thought of that!!!